# Error in self-hosting service stack webservice in F#

Tags: service, f#, servicestack

I am creating service using servicestack. I have copied self-hosting code from [github Wiki- servicestack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting). PFB code which i have written .

[image]

And I am getting below error.
 Please let me know what is error in this.

[image]

Comment: I would assume that the interface `IService` doesn't have a method with the signature of your `this.Any()` method. Your method takes a parameter of F# type  record (`Hello`) and returns also a F# record type (`HelloResponse`). C# don't have records so ServiceStack's `Any` has most certainly different method signature

Comment: Can you show what `IService` is?

Comment: Oh, and for the error with `main` - that's simple: you need to write `module` at the top of your file instead of `namespace`.

Comment: IService is interface defined inside Servicestack.Interfaces.DLL .

Comment: If it is `IService` from https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IService.cs then it has no declared members at all so there is nothing to implement